# Hibernate @ElementCollection does not work correctly

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an Entity in my [hibernate 4.2.6](http://hibernate.org/) java application as follow:

```
@Entity
public class Store {
   @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();

   /* Getter and Setter */
}
```

`Store` Table hase one record and For this record, I add two String `field`. I get all record of table as follow:

```
return sesseionFactory.getCurrentSession.createCriteria(Store.class).list()
```

But It return two record!. When I add 3 String `filed`, it return three record.

**Where is problem**?

Comment: You mean you inserted three records in the database? What is your expectation?

Comment: I add one rocord to `Store` Entity with 2 `fields`(`fields` is an `ArrayList` that its size is 2). It must return one record of Store with array of fields(size of this array must be 2).

Comment: Did you follow a tutorial? From the posted code there are no relations with an embeddable object made. Can you also post what are your tables with some dummy data in it?

Comment: I followed from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection)

Comment: Well, you have not done it completely have you?

Comment: What you see is normal and expected. You need to use a `select distinct` HQL query, or apply the DistinctRootEntity (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.html) result transformer to your criteria.

Comment: I change my query to `return sesseionFactory.getCurrentSession.createQuery('FROM Store`).list()` and it work correctly